# Update when pulling down the screen | ANDROID

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to code it to update the information from the Internet in my app with pulling down the screen?
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrDvq.jpg)

Thanks for answering!

Comment: SwipeRefreshLayout thats native in androi

Comment: What do you really want? Make the UI pull to refresh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the SwipeRefreshLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014846/how-to-use-the-swiperefreshlayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: paste the code in your layout file

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ListView
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:id="@+id/mListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Step 2: Open your java file and add these lines

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
      private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;


         public void onCreate(Bundle savedStateInstances){
        ....
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        }

   @Override
    public void onRefresh() {


       //implement the logic you want to do when the pull down happen.

//after completion of your logic add this line.
 swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example implemantation :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_items"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_recent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Then in your class on create :

```
        mItemsContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_items);
    mItemsContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

then some where in class :

```
   @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

       // after refresh code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `Pull to Refresh`. There are examples around. Check [this](http://guides.codepath.com/android/implementing-pull-to-refresh-guide) out.

Answer (score 0):

Use SwipeRefreshLayout like as

step1: make xml file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

step2: in your activity do this

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
        android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
        android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
        android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}
@Override 
public void onRefresh() {
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}, 5000);
}
```