# Why is SwipeRefreshLayout not working or take too much time?

Tags: android, kotlin

When swiping, it shows the loading icon, but nothing happens then.
Here is my code:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the SwipeRefreshLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014846/how-to-use-the-swiperefreshlayout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding that to your layout on its own does nothing. You have to handle the refresh event in your Kotlin code:

```
swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener { 
    reloadListData()                    // refresh your list contents somehow
    swiperefresh.isRefreshing = false   // reset the SwipeRefreshLayout (stop the loading spinner)
}
```