# Want to add Swipe To Refresh From My Firebase Data In The XML Page

Tags: firebase, layout, refresh, swipe, swiperefreshlayout

i'm facing difficulties to implement the swiperecycler view and i've successfully added the dependency to the build.gradle(app)
I want to refresh the roomlist after every swipe to down action from firebase!

Could anyone please share the whole code after adding swiperecycler view

Fragemnt_Main_Dashboard XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".Fragment.MainDashboard">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toollbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hii"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Hey"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="   "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hii"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/calender"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlack"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_calender"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_noresult"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Nothing Found"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toollbar"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.testing.clubhome.supporting.FullLengthListView
                android:id="@+id/roomsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:divider="@color/colorWhite"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nativead"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/createRoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selected_button"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_add" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="New Room"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainDashboard.Java

```
    package com.testing.clubhome.Fragment;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.testing.clubhome.Backend.VoiceService;
import com.testing.clubhome.Club.ClubHome;
import com.testing.clubhome.Pages.Calender;
import com.testing.clubhome.Pages.MainActivity;
import com.testing.clubhome.Pages.premiun;
import com.testing.clubhome.R;
import com.testing.clubhome.Room.RoomHome;
import com.testing.clubhome.Room.creaeRoom;
import com.testing.clubhome.Room.room;
import com.testing.clubhome.supporting.FullLengthListView;
import com.testing.clubhome.supporting.roomSearchAdapter;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainDashboard extends Fragment {

    TextView userName;
    ImageButton calender;
    LinearLayout createRoom,empty;
    FullLengthListView roomsList;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase,clubReference,userReference,roomReference;
    FirebaseUser user;
    ArrayList<String> onGoingRoom=new ArrayList<>();
    roomSearchAdapter roomSarch;
    boolean prouser=false;
    int roomremaing;

    private void Updatetoken(FirebaseUser user){
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersInfo").child(user.getUid())
                                    .child("token").setValue(Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getToken());
                        }

                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dashboard, container, false);
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabase=firebaseDatabase.getReference("UsersInfo").child(user.getUid());
        userReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("Connections");
        clubReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("ClubsInfo");
        roomReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("RoomsInfo");
        userName=view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        calender=view.findViewById(R.id.calender);
        createRoom=view.findViewById(R.id.createRoom);
        empty=view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        roomsList=view.findViewById(R.id.roomsList);




        createRoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createtheRoom();
            }
        });

        calender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Calender.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //Check for Ongoing rooms
        mDatabase.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("pro").exists()){

                    prouser=true;
                }else{
                    prouser=false;
                }
                if (dataSnapshot.child("roomremaining").exists()) {
                    roomremaing= Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("roomremaining").getValue().toString());
                }
                String name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                userName.setText(name);
                if(dataSnapshot.child("Room Participated").exists()){
                    final String onGoingRoomString = dataSnapshot.child("Room Participated").getValue().toString();




                    roomReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.getResult().exists()) {
                                if(task.getResult().child(onGoingRoomString).exists()) {

                                }
                                else{
                                    mDatabase.child("Room Participated").removeValue();

                                }
                            }else{
                                mDatabase.child("Room Participated").removeValue();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: consider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23016437/14692830

Comment: Hi beast, could you please add that recycler view in my code so that i can easily copy and paste into my code! Please i think it won't take you much time to do that so!!!!